# How to save tm_map() output to csv file?

Tags: r, csv, lda, topic-modeling

I am working on analyzing New article from mashable.com. The data that I have created looks like (has 14 articles for now, factor is popular or not_popular)

id    content           factor

1   some text data     popular

I want to do supervises Topic Modeling on this data using the LDA package of Jonathan Chang. I have tried to do some preprocessing on the data and here is the script for the same

```
require("ggplot2")
require("grid")
require("plyr")
library(reshape)
library(ScottKnott)
setwd("~/Desktop")
library(lda)
library(tm)
dataValues<- read.csv('Business.csv')

dim(dataValues)
## Text Pre-processing.
## Creating a Corpus from the Orginal Function
## interprets each element of the vector x as a document
CorpusObj<- VectorSource(dataValues$content);
CorpusObj<-Corpus(CorpusObj);
# remove \r and \n
remove.carrigae <- function(x) gsub("[\r\n]", "", x)
CorpusObj = tm_map(CorpusObj,remove.carrigae)
#remove Hyperlinks
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removeURL)
#remove special char
removeSPE <- function(x) gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ", x)
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removeSPE)
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removePunctuation) 
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removeNumbers)
#CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, stemDocument, language = "english") #Stemming the words 
CorpusObj<-tm_map(CorpusObj,stripWhitespace)
#CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, tolower) # convert all text to lower case
inspect(CorpusObj[14])

CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, PlainTextDocument)
#save in indiv text file
writeCorpus(CorpusObj, path = "~/Desktop/untitled_folder")
#write 1 file
writeLines(as.character(CorpusObj), con="mycorpus.txt")
inspect(CorpusObj[14])
```

I want to save the output of

```
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, PlainTextDocument)
```

to a .csv file and want each row(cell) to be 1 document 
the function     `writeCorpus(CorpusObj, path = "~/Desktop/untitled_folder")`
is just writing the last doc to the text file.

Also when I try to use the function `corpusLDA <- lexicalize(CorpusObj )`
after PlaintextDocument I get the following output [It has all the docs in the [1:2,1:6007] and the other 2 list are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SXYp.png)

Please guide me as to where am I going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: For this to be reproducible please provide "Businesses.csv" or give an example using built-in data

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzodQ9yTFHfMVEhEeU1hZkd2ZEU  Have the r script, business.csv and the output of the line writeCorpus(CorpusObj, path = "~/Desktop/untitled_folder") in the folder.. Thanks  @Hack-R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I inspect the `.txt` file this script creates, I see all of the different documents. They are however in a human un-friendly format.

[image]

Here's what I think you want:

```
pacman::p_load("ggplot2", grid, plyr, reshape, ScottKnott, lda,tm)

dataValues <- read.csv("business.csv")
dim(dataValues)
## Text Pre-processing.
## Creating a Corpus from the Orginal Function
## interprets each element of the vector x as a document
CorpusObj<- VectorSource(dataValues$content);
CorpusObj<-Corpus(CorpusObj);
# remove \r and \n
remove.carrigae <- function(x) gsub("[\r\n]", "", x)
CorpusObj = tm_map(CorpusObj,remove.carrigae)
#remove Hyperlinks
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removeURL)
#remove special char
removeSPE <- function(x) gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ", x)
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removeSPE)
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removePunctuation) 
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removeNumbers)
#CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, stemDocument, language = "english") #Stemming the words 
CorpusObj<-tm_map(CorpusObj,stripWhitespace)
#CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, tolower) # convert all text to lower case
inspect(CorpusObj[14])

CorpusObj <- tm_map(CorpusObj, PlainTextDocument)
#save in indiv text file
writeCorpus(CorpusObj)
#write 1 file
tmp <- CorpusObj[1]

dataframe<-data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(CorpusObj, `[`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=F)
write.csv(dataframe, "output.csv")
```

Comment: That is what i am trying to get.. a better version of this file.. I tried different functions to write the pre processed data to a csv file.. My end goal is to do pre processing on the business.csv file and get a new clean .csv for this reason i am trying to save the clean data in some manner.. later i want to use this cleaned csv for Supervised Latent Dirchlet allocation in R... As I said before using the tm_map output into the function lexicalize() is giving me the thing in the image(given in the original comment)..`corpusLDA <- lexicalize(CorpusObj)` i want the content part in each cell csv

Comment: @karankothari So, you just want the text documents in a way that's easy to read, right?

Comment: Yes. after pre processing so that i can do SLDA on the clean data

Comment: worked like magic.. Thanks.. Will post more questions if I have any

Comment: @karankothari Happy to help. Please mark as the solution if this solves your problem. :)